# sed delete line after specific character

Tags: regex, sed

I have a set of datasource URLs from which I'd like to extract the hostname/IP address from.
I've managed to get rid of the prefixes, but I have troubles with the parts after the hostname.

The after parts have various formats, that can look like this:

- empty (line ends with the hostname, no characters follow up)
- :portnumber
- :portnumber:string
- :portnumber/string
- /string
- //string

So, after the hostname I expect a :, a / or nothing. I want to delete everything after the hostname.
I am having troubles with the colons and slashes, especially if there are more than one of them. Take example of :portnumber:string

```
sed -r 's/(.*):.*/\1/
```

This would result in deleting :string, but :portnumber remains. And it doesn't handle slashes.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `'s,^([a-zA-Z]+://[^/:]*).*,\1,'`

Comment: suggestion: adding sample input lines with expected output will help to resolve your issue better...

Comment: Or, try `'s,^(([a-zA-Z]+://)?[^/:]*).*,\1,'` if the protocol can be missing... Really, adding some examples would help.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`s|([^:/]*)[:/].*|\1|`

Discussion:

`.*` is greedy, and matches `:`

So you need to match any character except `:` : `s/([^:]*):.*/\1/`

To expand that to forward slash matching, you want to switch to a different field separator for your substition.  Say `s|||` or `s###` rather than `s///` so that you don't have to escape the forward slash.

So, using vertical bars for the substitution separator:
`s|([^:/]*)[:/].*|\1|`

Comment: Cool, I didn't know I could use a different operator.
The above solution however, deletes some lines completely. Eg.
jdbc:sqlserver://hostname
Here's the complete command:
sed -r 's#.*<url>jdbc:(oracle:thin:@|db2:|.*sqlserver:|as400:)/*([^:/]*)[:/].*</url>#\2#'

Comment: @AttilaBoncok couldn’t test input because none was provided.   Probably could be fixed by making the first * a + to ensure \1 doesn’t match an empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's|[:/].*||'
```

Translation: "remove a colon or slash, along with anything that follows it."

Comment: This works, though so far it looks like I have to pipe the input through two sed's. But that might be because I didn't share the first half.

Comment: @AttilaBoncok: You could do `sed -e 'whatever' -e 's|[:/].*||'`, or maybe `sed 'whatever;s|[:/].*||'`.